# How to restrict the table row using js or jquery with out using style tag and class attribute for that row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to restrict the displaying the records of table.

I can able to restrict the table rows with style property of row.But when I am using that style it is giving the UI problems like on mouse over is missing for entire row.

Now mouse over should be there in this table on every table record.

I am using below code.

```
<tr style="display: block;"></tr>
```

Is there any way to hide the rows other than the above code.

I want to restrict the table row with out using the style property.

```
<c:forEach var="article" items="${vp_kb_articleList}" varStatus="loopStatus"> 
<tr id="<%=rowId++%>" class="myrow"> 
  <td class="vp_kb_article" > see this code <a class="detaillist" href="${vp_kb_articlePageUrl}?articleId=${article.id}"> ${article.title}<br> 
    <span class="vp_kb_details">${article.description}</span> 
    <span class="vp_kb_article_id">${article.id}</span> </a> 
  </td> 
</tr> 
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: please provide some code to look into the issue

Comment: <c:forEach var="article" items="${vp_kb_articleList}" varStatus="loopStatus">
<tr  id="<%=rowId++%>" style="display: block;">
<td class="vp_kb_article"  >  see this code
      <a class="detaillist"  href="${vp_kb_articlePageUrl}?articleId=${article.id}">
      ${article.title}<br>
           <span class="vp_kb_details">${article.description}</span>
      <span class="vp_kb_article_id">${article.id}</span>
           </a>
           </td>
         </tr>


</c:forEach>

Comment: @santhoshkumar: Please edit the code into the question with proper formatting.

Comment: Why should a row be hidden or displayed as a block ? in your case of course, i mean , how or when should it happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach var="article" items="${vp_kb_articleList}" varStatus="loopStatus"> 
<tr id="<%=rowId++%>" class="myrow"> 
  <td class="vp_kb_article" > see this code <a class="detaillist" href="${vp_kb_articlePageUrl}?articleId=${article.id}"> ${article.title}<br> 
    <span class="vp_kb_details">${article.description}</span> 
    <span class="vp_kb_article_id">${article.id}</span> </a> 
  </td> 
</tr> 
</c:forEach>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".myrow").hide();
});
```